# Fix text on a div

Tags: css, html, sass

I'm creating a website, and i saw that when I resize the window on my Mac (1270px), my text is in the good place (see picture).

But when I resize the window on a large screen, the text is lower (see picture).

I'm on a Wordpress so I can't do what ever I want ..

This is my CSS :

```
@media all and (max-width: 980px){
    .header-notre-vision:before, .header-notre-vision:after{
        display: none;
    }

    ul.ul-orange-notre-vision{
        padding: 0 !important;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1300px) {
  .header-content {
    h1 {
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
  }

  #section-notre-vision:before{
    content: "UNE OFFRE QUI MODERNISE ET AMÉLIORE VOTRE RELATION CLIENT.";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 30px auto 0 auto !important;
  }

  ul.ul-orange-notre-vision{
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 110px;

    li.li-orange-notre-vision{
      line-height: 3px;

      h4{
        strong{
          font-size: 15px;
        }
    }

// Icône "check"
  &:after{
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        font-size: 25px;
        content: "\f05d";
        position: relative;
        left: 170px;
        bottom: 19px;
      }
    }
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 980px) {
  .header-content {
    h1 {
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
  }

  .wrap-orange-notre-vision{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0;
    ul{
        margin-top: 36px !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Mac :
[image]

Large screen :

[image]

Do you have any idea how to ensure that the text does not go down?

Comment: have you looked at your viewport meta? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`  Its probably allowing the size to scale responsively. by the way, no pictures are visible.

Comment: I don't understand .. My <meta> tag is in WordPress files, and I didn't touch anything

Comment: sorry, I misread your question and got confused on what was happening.  This does not apply to your question.  Didn't get my comment removed or updated quickly as I got caught up in work stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In general, for responsive design it can work well for distances in relation to a container to use percentage values instead of pixel values.

For example you have this rule:

```
 ul.ul-orange-notre-vision{
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 110px;
```

Now I don't know how hight the parent element of that list is, but instead of using `margin-top: 110px;` you can try to write something like `margin-top: 20%;` (try around adjusting that value until it fits your needs) - this will remain at the same relation in all sizes.

However, if you use percentage values for vertical distances like in this example, it's also necessary that the parent element has a defined `height` setting - either a pixel value or again a percentage value, which again requires that the parents parent also has a defined `height` value and so on, up to the body element or to a pixel value for `height`.

Comment: Yeah I know it's nod a good idea to use pixels .. ^^ Wahou, it seems to be more difficult than I expected :/ Ok so I'll try something like this, thank you